# Custom UITextField delegate set to self initiates infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uitextfielddelegate

I am writing iPhone App in which I need custom UITextField class. For my text fields I need indent, image inside before the text and max characters. For this reason I created custom class based on UITextField. All my text fields will be based on this new class. I use Google and searched Stackoverflow and I find that in cases like mine I have to use `self.delegate = self;` during the `init` so I don't need to implement methods like `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` or `textFieldShouldEndEditing` inside my View Controller class. All my text fields will be created in storyboard so `initWithCoder`. As a result I receive infinite loop and App crash (I use simulator at this moment) after typing 1, 2 or 3 symbols. It is interesting that for numeric keyboard or password keyboard there is no such issue. Also if I type symbols on my Mac keyboard instead on the simulator there is no problem. I tried to debug but during the crash it jumps directly into loop and exist with error. 
How to overcome this problem?

P.S. I asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870007/i-receive-exc-bad-access-using-custom-uitextfield-how-to-trace-the-issue) when I receive infinite loop and there was comments that `self.delegate = self;` can cause such loop, but I see that this statement is widely used. May be I did not do this correctly, but I can not figure out how to make reusable class out of UITextField.

**EDIT:**
Here is my code:

On inti I initialize and set border color:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I start edit I change border color and set indent (indent set will be moved in property setter):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    // Change border of text field that is editing to orange
    textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

    UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _leftIndent, 10)];
    [self setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [self setLeftView:spacerView];

    return YES;
}
```

On finish editing I return back color:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    // Change border of text field that is edited to black
    textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

    return YES;
}
```

And on value change I check max characters:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    // Restrict number of symbols in text field to "maxSymbols"
    NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

    return newLength <= (int)_maxSymbols || returnKey;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your textFieldShouldBeginEditing and textFieldShouldEndEditing methods here?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I don't see anything obvious. Try to find out which line of your code causes your endless loop.

Comment: Nope, it is general. When I debug and pass 1 or 2 symbols in text field it starts infinite loop and crashes.

Comment: Hm... I tried your example and it seems that self.delegate = self is just isn't going to work on a UITextField. A searched a bit and it appears that the infinite loop is due to the way respondsToSelector: is implemented. Eventually, it tries to call respondsToSelector on it's delegate and ends up calling the [self respondsToSelector:] again and again.

Comment: You could try to search for a workaround, although, if you insist on avoiding the external delegate you could create a private class within your UITextField subclass implementation to do the delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can be actual answer, but I have work around which is the answer of my next question [How properly subclass UITextField in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998600/how-properly-subclass-uitextfield-in-ios) (from [justafinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876288/justafinger)). I don't make assignment `self.delegate = self;` in my custom control, but I have methods that are called from delegates in view controller.

I hope this can help people with problem like mine.